# How do I sort articles by Popularity?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting, probability

I have a table with thousands of records of news articles. On the website, there is a news listing page with an option to sort articles by popularity with an infinite scroll. The table looks something like this:

```
id | title | description | views | createdAt
```

The key columns for determining the popularity are views and createdAt.

What algorithm / formula can I implement to sort the articles by popularity?

Currently, I am just sorting by views in descending order, but that way the list will hardly ever update and show the same articles all the time.

Comment: I think this is off topic for SO. Maybe superuser would be more appropriate?

Comment: There are multiple options: 1st - add http://tablesorter.com/docs/ os something similar and sort the table on frontend. 2nd - add "query" parameters to headers as links like "?createdAt=desc", read that parameter and add it to your SQL call like @WaleedAhmed mentioned

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be to "penalize" articles by their age. E.g., for each day since the article was published, reduce the score by 100 (or some other arbitrary number that matches the amount of traffic your website has). This way older articles will slowly be pushed out and newer ones will get a chance to be viewed:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     articles
ORDER BY views - 100 * DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, createdAt) DESC
```

Comment: I like the idea, can use this in my projects.

Comment: Why not just sort by `createdAt=desc` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols instead of `view`s? as a secondary sorting column?

Comment: This is a great idea. However, I am wondering if there is a more dynamic way to calculate the multiplier for the penaly, so I don't have to hardcode 100 or some arbitrary number.

Comment: @littleibex A slightly more robust implementation I can think about is to decide up front how long you want an article  to be features (e.g., 7 days), and then subtract `MAX(views)/time_to_live`. This ensures that the article with the most views won't be featured for more than `time_to_live`, and any other articles will be featured for a proportionately shorter time.

Answer (score 0):

Simple do it as, hope it will work:

```
 order by views,createdAt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have one more column say 'lastView'

Idea is to print most recent popular items not just the popular.

In your query you can give the condition :
select * from table where created >= 'recentDate1' and lastView >= 'recentDate2' order by views desc; based on your necessity.

On every refresh you can just change the recent date through jQuery whcih will give you finite number of results. You can even reduce infinite loop/results.